# Using JavaEE Authorization Annotations for securing Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am trying to use Java authorization annotations e.g. @DenyAll, @RolesAllowed to secure the JAX-RS web services but its not working as expected. I am using Tomcat 7 to deploy the web service

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>AllMethods</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>a</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>co.edureka</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>a</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>abc</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/rs/client/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>

       <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>admin</role-name>
       <role-name>employee</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>   

    <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>    
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
    <role-name>employee</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>    
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

**Root Resource Class**

```
package co.edureka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;


@Path("/")
@RolesAllowed({"admin","employee"})
public class ClientResource{


    public static final HashMap<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    static{
        map.put(1, "Aftab Alam");  map.put(2, "Mahtab Alam");
    }

    @DenyAll
    @GET
    @Path("/client/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String retrieve(@PathParam("id") int id,@Context SecurityContext sc){
        if(sc.isUserInRole("admin") ){
            System.out.println("User is in role admin");
        }
        else if(sc.isUserInRole("employee")){
            System.out.println("User is in role employee");
        }
        System.out.println("Transport Secure : "+sc.isSecure());
        System.out.println("User : "+sc.getUserPrincipal());
        System.out.println("Authentication Mechanism : "+sc.getAuthenticationScheme());
        return map.get(id);
    }   
}
```

Note that I have used DenyAll annotation on the resource method but still I am able to execute the method

Console Output

```
User is in role admin
Transport Secure : false
User : User username="mahtab", roles="ValidUsers,admin"
Authentication Mechanism : BASIC
```

I have defined the users in tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="mahtab" password="alam" roles="ValidUsers,admin"/>
<user username="aftab" password="alam" roles="employee"/>
```

Comment: what are you expecting ? not clear

Comment: My question is how I am able to access resource method retrieve when I have used @DenyAll on the method resource

Comment: Try adding `<http-method>GET</http-method>` to the `<web-resource-collection>`. Also what's the request like?